# How to get meta of a kdb table using SQL?

Tags: sql, kdb

I am using a tool that connects to KDBs using jdbc driver. While the connection is successful, it is unable to retrieve metadata from tables. The way around is to construct an SQL query that fetches the meta.
I have found examples of SQL query from a q prompt but not the other way round.

Comment: What command are you sending to kdb to get the meta? Does `meta <tableName>`  not work?